# Finding Accurate BPM and Beat Time Values in Audio

Tags: audio, signal-analysis

I working on writing a program to get the BPM rate and the Beat Times in audio songs but I am having trouble trying to come up with reliable testing strategies for my design.What do I benchmark my BPM rates and Beat Times against? Should I just use other softwares or is there ways of checking if my BPM rates and beat times are correct? (apart from physically listening and tapping along to the song).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing your results against data annotated by a human listener is the way to go. You can try downloading some of the evaluation data from [MIREX](http://www.music-ir.org/mirex/) or look for other research databases.

Comment: Do you know how to interpret the beat tracking data from Mirex? They seem to give a set of 8 or so different sequences of beat times for each audio sample.I can't find anything explaining this on their site.